# frequency of unique values for 2d numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, count, unique

I have a 2-dimensional numpy array of following format:

[image]

now how to print the frequency of unique elements in this 2d numpy array, so that it returns `count([1. 0.]) = 1 and count([0. 1.]) = 1`? I know how to do this using loops, but is there any better pythonic way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`numpy.unique()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html), for axis=0, and pass `return_counts=True`, It will return a tuple with unique values, and the counts for these values.

```py
np.unique(arr, return_counts=True, axis=0)
```

**OUTPUT:**

```py
(array([[0, 1],
       [1, 0]]), array([1, 1], dtype=int64))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `collections.Counter`, it will give you a dictionary with the sublists as keys and number of occurrences as values

```
y = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.], [0., 1.]])
counter = collections.Counter(map(tuple, y))
print(counter[0., 1.]) # 2
```